# Are the “lectures” in the bobi verse books made up or based on real talks?

Tags: bobiverse

Througout the bobiverse series at the start of many chapters short lecture statements are given and proscribed to various speakers. These statement regard things such as AI, the development of 3D printers to be able to build anything at a molecular level and the development of interstellar exploration.

Is the author quoting real talks that he has seen and inspired his series here, or is this also all created?

Comment: I've twitted at the author to see if I can get any confirmation on why he chose those names for the other characters. I'm assuming that they're also references of some sort, but I'm blowed if i can work out what they relate to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the quotes are real (notably those from [Sun Tzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Tzu)) and others are made up by the author.

> **Q.** ***Heya, looking to find the origin of a reference you have in the first Bobiverse book. Chapter 14 intro. I’d like to find that or common content to reference for an article.***
>
> **Dennis E. Taylor**: *Sorry, that’s completely made up. Also, no one so far seems to have caught on that Lawrence Vienn is a [tuckerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckerization) of Larry Niven.*
>
> <sub><sup>http://dennisetaylor.org/about</sup></sub>

<s>I'm pretty sure that the other names; Stephen Carlisle and Eduard Guijpers are also similar in-jokes.</s>

The other names are entirely fictitious and aren't anagrams, just names invented by the author.

> **Q.** *If Lawrence Vienn = Larry Niven, then who are the other two (Stephen Carlisle and Eduard Guijpers)?*
>
> **Dennis E. Taylor:** ***I just made them up. But I wanted to get Niven in there.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter - 15 Mar 2019](https://twitter.com/Dennis_E_Taylor/status/1106573489513750528)</sup></sub>

---

Note also that the various synposia that supposedly spawned these quotes ("Exploring the Galaxy", "Designing a Von Neumann Probe") are set *in-universe*.

> I waggled my eyebrows at her and continued, *“And I just went to a couple of very interesting panels. Exploring the Galaxy and Designing a Von Neumann Probe.”*